# Fetch() function causing a resourse blocked by CORS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

App.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    character : {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=basf")
      .then(data => console.log(data));
    console.log("Hello World");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2>Hello World</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Error Message -

> Access to fetch at
>   'https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=basf' from origin
>   'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>
> Failed to Fetch

Can you please provide me how to get past this issue and get required data. I am using Github Jobs API and its showing this message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

Comment: Dont you nead to pass credentials in order to acess that API ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are several ways you can get it done

**ONE**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    character : {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=basf",{
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                })
      .then(data => console.log(data));
    console.log("Hello World");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2>Hello World</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**TWO**

Setting the `mode` parameter to `no-cors`.

```
fetch("https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=basf", {
      mode: "no-cors" // 'cors' by default
    }).then(data => console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

you can solve this from frontend side if you are facing cors issue. using-

`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/{type_your_url_here}`

```
  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=basf'
    )
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(data=>console.log(data))
  }
```

Working [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fi2vnq?file=index.js)

Comment: This works but aren't there  limitations to using  `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`?

Comment: @nibble No... you can use because internally it has implemented to secure HTTP call.

Comment: This is now not available as the server has been shut down.

Answer (score 0):

By using the create-react-app proxy feature you can solve this problem.

Add proxy property to your **package.json**:

```js
{
  // ...
  proxy: "https://jobs.github.com"
}
```

And then call the fetch function:

```js
fetch("http://localhost:300/positions.json?description=basf")
      .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the no-cors header

```
 fetch("https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=basf", {
      mode: "no-cors" // 'cors' by default
    }).then(data => console.log(data));
```

look in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-wood-5js3u)

I hope this answer helped you :)